# How do I level up quickly in Felspire?

Tags: felspire

It's difficult for me to level up after I reached level 100. Are there any strategies?

Comment: Hello gaminglover, just wanted to remind you that if the answer below DID help you, you can mark it as accepted. That way, the answerer gets 15 reputation and you even earn a bit of reputation too! Thanks, and happy posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are some personal experience. Hope it works for you

1. Daily quest are strongly recommended to be the first thing to do upon launching Felspire. Not only because they give a fair amount of EXP upon completion, but also provide a 1.5X EXP Potion, which lasts for 1 hour.
2. The Kill streak system gives extra experience for killing monsters in succession.
3. Teaming up with other players can receive up to 30% additional EXP if the teammates are all on the same map. This benefit is particularity useful for BOSS fights and special dungeons.
4. The Companion, Panda gives 50% extra EXP.
5. According to the servers world level (average lvl. of top 30 players) players with levels lower than that of the world level but higher than lvl.160 can enjoy a certain percent of extra EXP when killing creatures.
6. Praying is another efficient way to get Extra EXP.
7. If you are strong enough to join one of the top 3 guilds then participating in the GvG battles is another way to boost your EXP.
8. Dungeons are definitely a good way to get a great amount of EXP. Demon Abyss and Temple of Death are best places to level before reaching lvl.200. After lvl.200, tickets to these two Dungeons are not easy to get. Players could join a guild and take on the guild Realm Dungeons, here abundant EXP and rare loot awaits.
9. Finally, becoming a VIP is an efficient way to level up quickly. Every VIP enjoys 50% extra EXP. Should a player wish to progress more quickly and obtain exclusive item and gears, then it is a good idea to give VIP a try.